# Drag and position Image inside Picturebox and Select a Portion of the Image

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, picturebox

Hi I've C# forms application. I want to Load an Image into a picturebox and Drag the Image where I want. When I'm done with Dragging I added a checkbox 
to let users to click on a checkbox.

Then, user can use mouse to select a portion of image. That portion will be shown inside another picturebox. So, I did some search and came up with a solution 
which actually doesn't work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HCRLibrarytest
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private Point startingPoint = Point.Empty;
        private Point movingPoint = Point.Empty;
        private bool panning = false;
        Image _OrginalBitmap;
        Image _NewBitmap;
        private bool IsSelecting = false;
        private int X0, Y0, X1, Y1;
        static bool isimagepositioned = false;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_openimage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialog2 = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                Filter = "Bitmap Image (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg"
            };

            using (OpenFileDialog dialog = dialog2)
            {
                if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dialog.FileName))
                        {
                            this._OrginalBitmap = new Bitmap(dialog.FileName);
                            this.pb_fullimage.Image = this._OrginalBitmap;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void pb_fullimage_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_OrginalBitmap != null)
            {
                if(!isimagepositioned)
                {
                    panning = false;
                }

                else
                {
                    if (!IsSelecting) return;
                    IsSelecting = false;
                    pb_fullimage.Image = _OrginalBitmap;
                    int wid = Math.Abs(X0 - X1);
                    int hgt = Math.Abs(Y0 - Y1);
                    if ((wid < 1) || (hgt < 1)) return;
                    Bitmap area = new Bitmap(wid, hgt);
                    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(area))
                    {
                        Rectangle source_rectangle = new Rectangle(Math.Min(X0, X1), Math.Min(Y0, Y1), wid, hgt);
                        Rectangle dest_rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, wid, hgt);
                        gr.DrawImage(pb_fullimage.Image, dest_rectangle, source_rectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    }
                    pb_selectedportion.Image = area;
                }
            }
        }

        private void pb_fullimage_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_OrginalBitmap != null)
            {
                if (!isimagepositioned)
                {
                    panning = true;
                    startingPoint = new Point(e.Location.X - movingPoint.X,e.Location.Y - movingPoint.Y);
                }
                else
                {
                    _NewBitmap = new Bitmap(pb_fullimage.Image);
                    IsSelecting = true;
                    X0 = e.X;
                    Y0 = e.Y;
                }
            }
        }

        private void pb_fullimage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_OrginalBitmap != null)
            {
                if (!isimagepositioned)
                {
                    if (panning)
                    {
                        movingPoint = new Point(e.Location.X - startingPoint.X,e.Location.Y - startingPoint.Y);
                        pb_fullimage.Invalidate();
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    if (!IsSelecting) return;
                    X1 = e.X;
                    Y1 = e.Y;
                    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(_NewBitmap);
                    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
                    {
                        gr.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Math.Min(X0, X1), Math.Min(Y0, Y1), Math.Abs(X0 - X1), Math.Abs(Y0 - Y1));
                    }
                    pb_fullimage.Image = bm;
                }
            }
        }

        private void pb_fullimage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_OrginalBitmap != null && !isimagepositioned)
            {
                e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(_OrginalBitmap, movingPoint);
            }
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                isimagepositioned = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isimagepositioned = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I drag and check 'Image Positioned' and select using mouse move. It always gives me the the image that is relative to the original image position.

So, Can somebody help to fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since nobody answered me, I found an answer. This worked for me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HCRLibrarytest
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public Point startingPoint = Point.Empty;
        public Point movingPoint = Point.Empty;
        public bool panning = false;
        Image _OrginalBitmap;
        public static Image _NewBitmap;
        public bool IsSelecting = false;
        public int X0, Y0, X1, Y1;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void btn_openimage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialog2 = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                Filter = "Bitmap Image (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg"
            };

            using (OpenFileDialog dialog = dialog2)
            {
                if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dialog.FileName))
                        {
                            this._OrginalBitmap = new Bitmap(dialog.FileName);
                            this.pb_fullimage.Image = this._OrginalBitmap;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void pb_fullimage_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (pb_fullimage.Image != null)
            {
                if (!checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    panning = false;
                }

                else
                {
                    if (!IsSelecting) return;
                    IsSelecting = false;
                    pb_fullimage.Image = _NewBitmap;
                    int wid = Math.Abs(X0 - X1);
                    int hgt = Math.Abs(Y0 - Y1);
                    if ((wid < 1) || (hgt < 1)) return;
                    Bitmap area = new Bitmap(wid, hgt);
                    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(area))
                    {
                        Rectangle source_rectangle = new Rectangle(Math.Min(X0, X1), Math.Min(Y0, Y1), wid, hgt);
                        Rectangle dest_rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, wid, hgt);
                        gr.DrawImage(_NewBitmap, dest_rectangle, source_rectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    }
                    pb_selectedportion.Image = area;
                }
            }
        }

        public void pb_fullimage_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (pb_fullimage.Image != null)
            {
                if (!checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    panning = true;
                    startingPoint = new Point(e.Location.X - movingPoint.X, e.Location.Y - movingPoint.Y);
                }
                else
                {
                    IsSelecting = true;
                    X0 = e.X;
                    Y0 = e.Y;
                }
            }
        }

        public void pb_fullimage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (pb_fullimage.Image != null)
            {
                if (!checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    if (panning)
                    {
                        movingPoint = new Point(e.Location.X - startingPoint.X, e.Location.Y - startingPoint.Y);
                        pb_fullimage.Invalidate();
                        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pb_fullimage.ClientSize.Width, pb_fullimage.ClientSize.Height))
                        {
                            pb_fullimage.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, pb_fullimage.ClientRectangle);
                            try { bitmap.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "draw.jpg"); }
                            catch (Exception ex) { Console.Write(ex.ToString()); }
                        }
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    if (!IsSelecting) return;
                    X1 = e.X;
                    Y1 = e.Y;
                    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromStream(File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "draw.jpg"))));
                    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
                    {
                        gr.DrawRectangle(Pens.WhiteSmoke, Math.Min(X0, X1), Math.Min(Y0, Y1), Math.Abs(X0 - X1), Math.Abs(Y0 - Y1));
                    }
                    _NewBitmap = bm;
                }
            }
        }

        public void pb_fullimage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (pb_fullimage.Image != null && !checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(pb_fullimage.Image, movingPoint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```